# Visual Studio Code - better diff colors

Tags: git, diff, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code to view Git diffs. But the diff is harder to read than the Visual Studio 2017 diff.
Is it possible to have only one color in Visual Studio Code?

Visual Studio 2017 diff (easy to read):

[image]

Visual Studio Code diff (almost impossible to read):

[image]

Comment: **See Also**: [How to change diff color Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50680317/1366033)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is not possible. There are only options to change color for line background or line border. From the [Visual Studio Code manual](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference#_diff-editor-colors):

For coloring inserted and removed text, use either a background or a border color, but not both.

- `diffEditor.insertedTextBackground`: Background color for text that got inserted.
- `diffEditor.insertedTextBorder`: Outline color for the text that got inserted.
- `diffEditor.removedTextBackground`: Background color for text that got removed.
- `diffEditor.removedTextBorder`: Outline color for text that got removed.